# how to add css attributes to a radio and input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, radio-button

I have a small box on within my HTML, along with 3 radio buttons to add the positioning properties, fixed, absolute, and relative. I also have 2 text input options to move the box an inputted amount of pixels from the top and another input to move the div some odd pixels from the left. Here is my HTML:

```
  <div id="input">
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="position" value="fixed"> Fixed<br>
      <input type="radio" name="position" value="absolute"> Absolute<br>
      <input type="radio" name="position" value="relative"> Relative <br>
      <br>Top:<br>
      <input type="text" name="top"> px
      <br>
      <br>Left:<br>
      <input type="text" name="left"> px
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" class="button" value="submit" onClick="computeForm(this.form)">
    </form>
  </div><!--closes input-->
</div><!--closes text-area-->

  <div id="image">
    <div id="box">
    </div><!--closes box-->
</div><!--closes image-->
```

I'm really new at Javascript and jQuery, and I the more I go without guidance the more I seem to confuse myself...

Comment: What are you looking into modifying with those properties?

Comment: You should check out this W3School tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_html.asp. I am sure you can do what you want by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first get the data in the form, the set the style on the element. Here's an example:

```
function computeForm(form){
  // Get form data
  var data = new FormData(form);

  // Assign data to variables
  var position = data.get("position");
  var left = data.get("left");
  var top = data.get("top");

  // Get box element
  var box = document.getElementById("box");

  // Set style
  box.style.position = position;
  box.style.left = left + "px";
  box.style.top = top + "px";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ju79h33y/

Comment: No problem, don't forget to set as answered

Answer (score 1):

To style a text input you can add the style attribute to the element:

```
<input style="border: 1px solid blue" type="text" name="left">
```

Here it is implemented in your code: http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/QvpJyv?editors=1010

Radio buttons are restricted on what can and can't be styled. A common method is to hide the input and replace it with a custom object. Here is a tutorial:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953